# Can I edit Delayed chained payment amount of multiple receivers?

Tags: paypal, delay, payment, chained

In delayed payment system ,There are one master account and different multiple receivers .
I wish to edit the Amount of each receiver before distributing amount to receivers .

Answer (score 0):

currently this feature you are looking for is not supported in Delayed chain payments.  You cannot edit the amount that needs to distributed for which you made  transaction already.